# How to click Cancel button one time in SearchBar when it's not focus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I add the SearchBar view in NavigationBar.

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
```

When I am searching...

[image]

The search is complete...

[image]

If I want to cancel (remove) SearchBar, I must tap to Cancel button TWO time for remove SearchBar. (one time for focus SearchBar and one time for tap Cancel).

How can I just one tap to Cancel like (x) button (clear text button) in SearchBar?
or How can SearchBar always focused? (on this way I can tap Cancel for close SearchBar only one tap)

Comment: you want to hide the cancel button when click on cancel?

Comment: I want to close (remove) SearchBar by tap Cancel button one time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't dismiss your keyboard after search

> > remove this line  [searchBar resignFirstResponder]

It will work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Implement the search bar delegate method as :

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar {
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        [mySearchBar setAlpha:0.0];
    }
```

Hope you have got the idea by doing this. Also you can add it directly to navigation controller, itself, if you want & then play with Showing/ hiding the `searchBar` alone.

Comment: try this it will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    controller.active = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:controller.searchBar];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:controller.searchBar];
}

- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView  {

    tableView.frame = self.archiveListTblView.frame;
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    controller.active=NO;

    [self.view addSubview:controller.searchBar];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When search bar has resigned from first responder, cancel button is disabled.

So you should enable the cancel button manually.

Try this:

```
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];

[(UIButton *)[searchBar valueForKey:@"_cancelButton"] setEnabled:YES];
```